# Function to assign sequence keys to an array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array of unique colors which is selected from a table. But keys of that particular array is not in sequence order due to some calculations. Now I wish to assign a sequence numbers to that array...  Is any function to change keys of array..
Thanks...

```
Array(
[81]=>yellow 
[86]=>gray
[93]=>wine
[103]=>marigold
[125]=>maroon
[134]=>pewter
[142]=>forestgreen
[151]=>grey
)
```

i wish to change this array to

```
Array(
[1]=>yellow 
[2]=>gray
[3]=>wine
[4]=>marigold
[5]=>maroon
[6]=>pewter
[7]=>forestgreen
[8]=>grey)
```

Comment: `array_values($array)`?

Comment: Not sure I understand you. Could you show the array and what you want to change it to?

Comment: @DCoder is probably right.

Comment: Without knowing the desired order and the current order no one has any hope of helping you on this one.

Comment: Please give a better explanation what you actually trying to do.

Comment: Try to set Order In array not change Key of array.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort your array by some calculation, you can use [usort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php), which sorts an array by using a callback function. In this callback function, you can compare two elements of the array and decide (by any means you need) which one goes first. Read through the examples on the page I linked to learn more!

Answer (score 0):

use: `sort($color);` check the examples from this link: [sort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php)